# How to Keep Fixed Nav Bar In Front and Not Behind Page Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, absolute

So I'm building my first personal website and I have an autoplaying presentation on my homepage (i have like 5 total pages, but i just started working on this). I recently finished making my nav bar at the top and used the table tag to space it out, color, etc.

I then went to try and make the presentation underneath. I finished it and when I scrolled, I saw that my nav bar was going behind my presentation and the two bars on the side filling it so it would have 100% width and after I scrolled past the presentation, the nav bar returned to being on top of text.

The nav bar is fixed and the slideshow and side colors are absolute. I have no clue how to make it so my nav bar is always going to show and be at the top of the page regardless of how far I've scrolled.

I couldn't post the code from my html and css because the formatting of this post apparently, so I  just used some online text host:
[Link](http://freetexthost.com/uxxsnnh4v2)

I'll try posting the code for the HTML:

```
<!-- Here is where the top nav starts -->
<table bgcolor="#C6D9FA" style="width:100%;position:fixed;top:0%;">
<tr>
    <td><a href="Homepage.html"><div id="topnavlinks">Homepage</div></a> 
</td>
    <td><a href="AboutMe.html"><div id="topnavlinks">About Me</div></a> 
</td>
    <td><a href="Portfolio.html"><div id="topnavlinks">Portfolio</div></a> 
</td>
    <td><a href="Extracurriculars.html"><div 
id="topnavlinks">Extracurriculars</div></a></td>
    <td><a href="Contact Me.html"><div id="topnavlinks">Contact Me</div> 
</a> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Here is where the top nav ends -->

<div id="section1background">
<!-- Here is where the autoplaying slideshow starts -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="TrackRun1.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="Graduation1.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="HasHeightSmile.jpg" 
style="width:100%"> 
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="Lazar.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="MirrorWarp.jpg" style="width:100%"> 
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="SpringTrack2017.jpg" 
style="width:100%"></div>
<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="TrackDinner2018-1.jpg" 
style="width:100%"></div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the CSS:

```
#Title{font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size:54px;
color:blue;}

#Text{font-family:Carter One, cursive;
font-size:40px;
color:black;
margin-top:5%;
}

a{text-decoration:none;
font-family:Carter One, cursive;

color:black}

html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

a:hover { 
  text-decoration:underline;
}

#topnavlinks{font-size:40px;}

/* HEADER COMPLETE */

/* SECTION 1: AUTO-PLAY SLIDESHOW */

* {box-sizing:border-box}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left:25%;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

 #section1background {
      background-color: grey;
      height: 74.3%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 6.9%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: You really need to post your code here so people can help you.  Just pick out the relevant parts.  Using the code snippet tool is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use z-index to always bring it on to top
Use CSS

```
table{
 Width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
}
```